# how do I change a URL with form to include additional selection

Tags: html, ajax, url, webforms

I am trying to modify the following URL:

[`https://sslecal2.investing.com/?columns=exc_importance&category=_employment,_economicActivity,_inflation,_credit,_centralBanks,_confidenceIndex,_balance,_Bonds&importance=1,2,3&features=datepicker,timezone,timeselector,filters&countries=5&calType=day&timeZone=15&lang=51`](https://sslecal2.investing.com/?columns=exc_importance&category=_employment,_economicActivity,_inflation,_credit,_centralBanks,_confidenceIndex,_balance,_Bonds&importance=1,2,3&features=datepicker,timezone,timeselector,filters&countries=5&calType=day&timeZone=15&lang=51)

This takes me to a table view but I would like to change the date to be a specific date. I can alter the date range to be eg. from 2023-12-06 to 2023-12-06.

Once I do this, I can see (with DevTools) that there is some kind of request (to ajax.php) that goes through that specifies `dateFrom=2023-12-06` & `dateTo=2023-12-06`

but if I add those to the long URL, nothing changes.

Is there a way of doing this in 1 request? I don't know much about web requests.

I was trying to use this in Obsidian as an iframe.

the addition of the extra features makes no difference.